# PHP Custom font vs asp.net mvc

Tags: php, apache, iis, fonts, web

I am interested in adding a custom font to a php website using an apache/nginx.
I would like to have browser support for IE7+, Safari, Chrome, Mozilla, Opera.

Normally, I work with ASP.NET MVC on a Windows Server with IIS 6. There, I just have to install the font file on the server which in turn lets me use:

```
font-family: 'custom-font';
```

and this works in any browser (at least the newer versions) on any client machine.

Can someone explain how does this work on php/apache?

Comment: I have no related experience at all, but this is a head-scratcher: how is it possible for this to work after "just installing the font file on the server"? How does the font get downloaded by the browser and used to render without any additional setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) has a wide selection of royalty-free, open-source and similarly licensed fonts ready for download, as well as a CSS font kit generator, which allows you to upload a font file in TTF or OTF format, select a few options, and it will spit out a zip file containing a stylesheet and a bunch of font files that you can simply drop in your web project's css directory. Import the font stylesheet into your main stylesheet, and you're ready to go. Or use the provided stylesheet as a basis for your own.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.designcourse.com/articles/1/css/55-CSS-Custom-Fonts

Second result on [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=css+custom+font)